# Referencing DLL, Compiling, DLL versioning

Tags: c#, .net

After years in .NET, I'm asking a basic question. One kid just out of college asked me this and I was suddenly confused!

I am referencing a IBM DATA DB2 DLL in my .NET project. The version we used initially was 9.7.0.2. So after we ran some tests, we upgraded the IBM DATA DLL to version 9.7.6.2.

Now the question is, should I recompile my code and then run it or can I directly replace the IBM DATA DLL in my build directory and will it run fine?

When should we ideally recompile our code?

Thanks
Soni

Comment: Honestly, if you update your project to use any different version of a 3rd party DLL, you _should_ at least try to recompile your code to make sure everything is fine with regards to API changes. If there are documented (or undocumented) API changes, then you could be in for runtime exceptions when your code tries to access a member that no longer exists. Unless you're pressed for time and don't have the luxury of recompiling, or updating from a trusted source that you know won't change APIs, then you should recompile and re-run tests to make sure everything is A-OK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually all depends on the DLL and the 3rd party that produced it. You need to look at the documentation and look for deprecated and modified functions (are you calling any of them?) And even if the doc says that nothing was changed and deprecated you should still do a regression test. Docs are not code, and the code is the truth that matters.

In a perfect world nothing would ever change or be deprecated in a public API and the writers of the DLL (interface) would just add new functions. Unfortunately, we can't count on that.

In brief: If any of the functions you're calling in the DLL were modified or deprecated, you have to rebuild, otherwise no.

Comment: +1. In ideal world (and when documentation says something like "123 version is backward compatible with 100,111,122") you can just drop DLL in. You may need to add policy fr version redirects in config file if you are using exact versions of assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you referenced DLL. In Solution Explorer, select your project and expand References in it. Select DLL and look at Property Editor window for property **"Specific Version"**. If it is set to false, then you can just replace binary in output, otherwise your application will throw error if it will not find that exact version of DLL.

Comment: This step is not sufficient for signed applications. You need to override the DLLs lookup or load them manually at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Version of library must not be changed unless you're specifically targeting one (as [when using entity framework and mysql adapter](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/09/getting-mysql-work-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)), then you'll need to change the version number in order to work. Other case occurs when API change (not frequently, not ideally [but it happens](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/155-social-media/2501-facebook-developers-face-disruption-.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, third party DLL's should be backwards compatible. However, that is not always the case and you should recompile when upgrading to ensure that it is. If you swap versions of a DLL without compiling you risk running into a variety of runtime errors that could have easily been detected with compilation / testing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to recompile your code. That is the benefit of a dynamically linked library.